# Carousel moves under nav on mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't figure out why my carousel is going below my nav. I've tried adjusting the position of property of my nav in relation to the carousel and still nothing. I am using Bootstrap 3. Besides all of Bootstraps native styles which are untouched, here is what I've added. I feel like I am not wrapping it in a certain class Bootstrap needs?

[image]

```
<header>
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid text-center">
                    <nav class="nav">
                        <ul class="pull-right">
                            <li>{{ HTML::link('/', 'Home') }}</li>
                            <li>{{ HTML::link('/', 'Products') }}</li>
                            <li>{{ HTML::link('/', 'About') }}</li>
                            <li>{{ HTML::link('/', 'Locations') }}</li>
                            <li>{{ HTML::link('/', 'Contact') }}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>          
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>      
        </div>
    </header>

<div id="carousel-id" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-id" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x580">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x580">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x580">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-id" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The carousel is below the navigation header because you wrote it like this in your html.. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Sebsemillia I am trying to have it stack directly underneath my nav across mobile and tablet.

Comment: Ah I think I know what you mean. On smaller screen devices the text of the slider get's moved out on the top of the slider box? This is because of the ratio of your image and because of the size of the text. Try making the text smaller on small grid breakpoints or remove some of it with `.hidden-sm` for example.

Comment: @Sebsemillia Ah, perfect! That makes sense now. If you put this in an answer format I can accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your carousel get's cut off on smaller screen sizes is, that the text is too big for this sizes and therefore doesn't act responsive.

You have several options to avoid this.

1.) Hide some text on smaller screen sizes with the helper classes like `.hidden-sm`. [Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

2.) Make the text smaller on small screen sizes.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .carousel-inner h1 { 
       font-size: 12px; 
   }
   .carousel-inner p {
       font-size: 8px;
   }
}
```

And as crazymatt stated as well, in your header section there is an closing `<div>` that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need your text to be responsive based on the size of the browser width for smaller resolutions. One way to achieve this is to add `@media` to your custom CSS file.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
   h1 { font-size: 14px; }
   p {font-size: 10px;
}
```

I have added a [JS.Fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/dd7dc7nj/) showing an example of this. You will need to add the necessary screen sizes to get it to work for what you want.

BTW in the code you posted you have an extra `</div>` that needs to be removed in the header section.